# XSL - Remove Null Tags and Retain Spaces

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a need to delete null nodes, but retain the nodes with a space as the value for a specific attribute, "DELETE". I'm not that familiar with XSL...How can I remove null values, but retain values of space?

This is preferably for only nodes with the action "DELETE". For example, when the action is "DELETE", no matter what the other node names are (because they will change), null valued children should be deleted. If this is not possible, I will settle for removing null values from the entire XML file, which the code for this is working and listed below. However it does not retain spaces and is not for just the attribute "DELETE".  Examples below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<test xmlns:n0="http://mynamespace">
 <Value Action="DELETE">
    <Example1> </Example1>
    <Test2 />
    <Example3></Example3>
 </Value>
 <Value Action="UPDATE">
   <space> </space>
    <null />
    <null2></null2>
 </Value>
</test>
```

Expected Result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<test xmlns:n0="http://mynamespace">
   <Value Action="DELETE">
     <Example1> </Example1>
   </Value>
   <Value Action="UPDATE">
     <space> </space>
     <null />
     <null2></null2>
   </Value>
</test>
```

Remove All Nulls:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
version="1.0">
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:if test=". != '' or ./@* != ''">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="@*">
        <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}">
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
        </xsl:attribute>
   </xsl:template>
       <xsl:template match="text() | comment() | processing-instruction()">
       <xsl:copy />
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I have updated my question. Thanks.

Comment: Question edited.

Answer (score 1):

You need:

1. An *identity template* to copy all input.
2. A template matching each node meeting both the following criteria:

   - it is contained within *Value* node with *Action* attribute set to *DELETE*,
   - its name contains *null*,

   to ignore such nodes.

   It is a more general and concise solution than individual templates
   for each node name (*null*, *null2*, ...).
3. Optionally, a template "blocking" whitespace-only text nodes, containing
   a *newline* char. The reason is to block *newline* text nodes
   between your tags, but "pass" e.g. spaces contained within `space` tags.

So the whole script can look like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="Value[@Action = 'DELETE']/*[contains(name(), 'null')]"/>

  <xsl:template match="text()[not(normalize-space())][contains(.,'&#xA;')]"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

Comment: @Valdi_Bo Your code is good only in case when nodes for removing start with "null", if the value will have <TESTnull> - that won't work. Safety method is to use contains, please see my edited example.

Comment: You gave only example tags, which names **start** with *null*. If the task is to eliminate all tags which **contain** *null*, then the second predicate must include *contains* function in place of *starts-with* (as I have just changed in the script).

Answer (score 0):

Copy all nodes and match avoiding nodes in next templates, see below XSL (**edited**):

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">       
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="no" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <!--copy all nodes--> 
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">            
        <xsl:copy>                
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />           
        </xsl:copy>        
    </xsl:template>
    <!--preventing spaces between nodes-->
    <xsl:template match="text()">
        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space()" />
    </xsl:template>    
    <!--match all elements which contain null for DELETE with doing nothing in template-->       
    <xsl:template match="/test/Value[@Action='DELETE']/*[contains(name(), 'null')]" />

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Result (**edited**):

```
<test xmlns:n0="http://mynamespace">
    <Value Action="DELETE">
        <space/>
    </Value>
    <Value Action="UPDATE">
        <space/>
        <null/>
        <null2/>
    </Value>
</test>
```

Comment: Consider also `<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>` to remove spaces between nodes.

Comment: Is this specific to only node names "null" and "null2"? I would want to remove null values for any node with that action.

Comment: @Toya I have edited XSL code, right now it is more dynamic - it will remove all elements which contain "null" in name (e.g. it will remove such elements as "tttnull", "null2" or just "null"). Also added preventing spaces between nodes - thanks for note Parfait.

Comment: Thanks so much, however I used the "null" names as an example. What I mean is it should be dependent on the action not the children names. I will update my example.